# How to send a list of requests exising inside one server to another server automatically

Tags: spring, multithreading, load-balancing, executorservice

My company gives me one existed project of a server where the client sends requests to this server, and by sockets, the requests are sent to another servers. The 2nd servers then processed the request and sent back the responses to the first server which then choose the last response to the client in a timeout predefined.
Now I have to put one new feature for this project for the 2nd option when the client wants to send the request to the 1st server only without waiting for responses from the 2nd one. When the first server has received the request, it will send the confirmation to the client. Now is the story of two servers.
My question is I want to know how we can use multithreading or ExecutiveService or something to manage two tasks at the same time. One task is to send the confirmation to the client. Another one is to communicate with the 2nd server and send the request as well as received the responses from this server.
Thank you so much for any guidance.

I did the first one and I don't know how to make the first server check the request lists automatically to send them to the second one.